# In EmailMultiAlternatives attach and attach_alternative both at time is not working

Tags: django, pdf, email-attachments

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
subject, from_email, to,bcc = 
request.POST['sub'],'fulfillment@***.com', lead.mailid,email_ccaddress
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, "", from_email, [to])
filepdf = open("Plan.pdf",'rb').read()
msg.attach("Plan.pdf",filepdf,'application/pdf')
msg.attach_alternative(request.POST['bodyofmail'], "text/html")
msg.content_subtype = 'html'
msg.send()
```

using 
Django 1.11.3
python3 
EmailMultiAlternatives

Individually both are working fine but once we run this code with attachment and attach_alternative HTML only pdf attachment is receiving in an email server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `content_subtype` on the message, and then attaching a separate `text/html` alternative. Doing both of these together doesn't make sense - it means that the mail client receives two `text/html` alternatives in the email and doesn't know which to render. It will just use the first.

Either remove the `content_subtype`, or put your html body in the `body` argument and drop the `attach_alternative`. In the latter case you can stop using `EmailMultiAlternative` and just use the `EmailMessage` class.